# Can a closed parametrized curve also be a smooth parametrized curve?

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors

I am studying Calculus from the book *Calculus with Concepts in Calculus 6th Edition* by Denny Gulick and Robert Ellis. Within the book, in section 12.4, the concept of parametrization and the different categories of parametrization is introduced. According to it:

> A curve $C$ is closed if it has a parametrization whose domain is a closed interval
> $[a, b]$ such that $r(a) = r(b)$, but otherwise $r(t_1) \neq r(t_2)$ for $t_1 \neq t_2$, with at most finitely many exceptions.

> A vector-valued function $r$ defined on an interval $I$ is smooth if $r$ has a
> continuous derivative on $I$ and $r(t) \neq 0$ for each interior point $t$. A curve $C$ is smooth if it has a smooth parametrization.

Now consider this example: the parametrization of a unit circle centered at the origin given by $r(t) = cos(t)i + sin(t)j$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ where $i$ and $j$ are unit vectors along the x and y directions. This satisfies the conditions for a closed parametrization but it also satisfies the conditions of a smooth parametrization. So is it both?

Comment: Sure, there's no reason the conditions can't overlap.

Comment: @PrincessEev Oh okay, I thought so too but wasn't sure and couldn't find any explicit information stating so anywhere else online. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Try to parametrize the boundary of the square so that it is smooth. It is a nice exercise.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Is it even possible to make it smooth? The only way I see it is to make it piecewise smooth.

Comment: It's like driving a car along the boundary of the square. You slow down to zero speed  at every corner and then gently speed up after turning $90$ degrees.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yeah, I agree but what I was saying was that you can only represent it as a piecewise function of 4 line segment equations. Unless you have something better in mind?

Comment: You can represent the boundary of the square as $[a,b]\ni t\to (x(t,),y(t))$ such that both functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are $C^1$. on $[a,b].$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$x(t)=\begin{cases}\sin^3 t& -{\pi\over 2}\le t\le {\pi \over 2}\\ 
1 & {\pi\over 2} \le t\le {3\pi\over 2}\\
-\sin^3t & {3\pi\over 2}\le t\le {5\pi\over  2} \\ -1 & {5\pi \over 2}\le t\le {7\pi\over 2}\end{cases}$$
$$y(t)=\begin{cases}-1& -{\pi\over 2}\le t\le {\pi \over 2}\\ 
-\sin^3t & {\pi\over 2} \le t\le {3\pi\over 2}\\
1 & {3\pi\over 2}\le t\le {5\pi\over  2} \\ \sin^3t & {5\pi \over 2}\le t\le {7\pi\over 2}\end{cases}$$
Then $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ parametrize the boundary of the square $|x|,|y|\le 1.$ Moreover $r\in C^{(3)}.$

**Remark** I guess there is a misprint in OP: the smooth parametrization requires that $r'(t)\neq 0,$ i.e. the speed does not vanish. The parametrization above does not satisfy that, as $r'(t)$ vanishes at $4$ points.

Concerning the circle $r'(t)=(-\sin t,\cos t )$ thus $\|r'(t)\|=1.$